# Change system date,time

Tags: c#, date, time

Hi I know this has been asked before but I need help changing system datetime in c#. While doing  a google search I found a website which suggested the following code

```
public struct SYSTEMTIME 
{    
    public ushort wYear,wMonth,wDayOfWeek,wDay, wHour,wMinute,wSecond,wMilliseconds;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public extern static void GetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

/// <param name="lpSystemTime">[in] Pointer to a SYSTEMTIME structure that
/// contains the current system date and time.</param>
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

static void Main()
{    
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
    GetSystemTime(ref st);
    Console.WriteLine("Adding 1 hour...");
    st.wHour = (ushort)(st.wHour + 1 % 24);
    if (SetSystemTime(ref st) == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("FAILURE: SetSystemTime failed");
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Setting time back...");
    st.wHour = (ushort)(st.wHour - 1 % 24);
    SetSystemTime(ref st);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
    Console.Read();
}
```

But when I run it in my system it shows no change in the current date/time. Should  I make any changes?
Edit: Got the message FAILURE: SetSystemTime failed when I try to run

Comment: Is this for e.g. testing purposes? It's usually better in such situations to abstract out the clock (so, remove any direct calls to `DateTime.Now`) rather than fiddling with the system's actual time.

Comment: This code changes date and revert it's back. Unless you get "FAILURE: SetSystemTime failed" to console - time is been successfully changed..  But some milliseconds.. Remove "time-reverting part", and tune code for your needs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually hav a program which is supposed to generate data for a particular year specified by user. Thought it'd work to change system dateTime whenever user wants message for that particular year

Comment: What version of Windows do you want to run this code on?  Because I am thinking is the user is not part of the administrator group, it might not work.

Comment: @BlackFrog Mostly for testing really...in windows xp

Comment: @Drake, if it's your code - make abstractions and change "Virtual Time" via them - it's better, faster, more trouble-less. I totally agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever - it's very bad practice, unless you vary rare special situation. Testing - is not that sort of thing.

Comment: The calling process must have the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege. This privilege is disabled by default. The SetSystemTime function enables the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege before changing the system time and disables the privilege before returning. See the error code to confirm.

Comment: @Arno &rufanov Thanx for the help guys...appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

you should use coredll.dll to archive this..

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
private extern static void GetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
private extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);


private struct SYSTEMTIME 
{
    public ushort wYear;
    public ushort wMonth; 
    public ushort wDayOfWeek; 
    public ushort wDay; 
    public ushort wHour; 
    public ushort wMinute; 
    public ushort wSecond; 
    public ushort wMilliseconds; 
}

private void GetTime()
{
    // Call the native GetSystemTime method 
    // with the defined structure.
    SYSTEMTIME stime = new SYSTEMTIME();
    GetSystemTime(ref stime);

    // Show the current time.           
    MessageBox.Show("Current Time: "  + 
        stime.wHour.ToString() + ":"
        + stime.wMinute.ToString());
}
private void SetTime()
{
    // Call the native GetSystemTime method 
    // with the defined structure.
    SYSTEMTIME systime = new SYSTEMTIME();
    GetSystemTime(ref systime);

    // Set the system clock ahead one hour.
    systime.wHour = (ushort)(systime.wHour + 1 % 24);
    SetSystemTime(ref systime);
    MessageBox.Show("New time: " + systime.wHour.ToString() + ":"
        + systime.wMinute.ToString());
}
```

I have not tested it. but I hope it will work

Comment: It's kernel32.dll exported function. It's don't exists in coredll.dll. Code in TS example is totally fine and working.

Comment: @rufanov it worked earlier to me.. and this is from msdn documentation     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172517(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: coredll one is throwing an exception tho...says its not supported

Comment: @Chandan Pasunoori, In this documentation clearly written that it's available only in currently abandoned "Microsoft .NET Compact Framework" project - very restricted version of .NET Framework that has been available on also obsolete Windows CE 6(and Windows Mobile 6) in 2006-2009 years.